# How To Set Different Footers For Different Pages In Itext Pdf Document

Tags: java, itext

I generate a PDF document with itext. Document has two part.First part should have different footer, second part should have different footer.How can I achieve this problem.I already try this code blocks:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream fileOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 145);

FooterPageEvent1 event1 = new FooterPageEvent1();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOut);
writer.setPageEvent(event1);
document.open();
.....
FooterPageEvent2 event2 = new FooterPageEvent2();
PdfWriter writer2 = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOut);
writer2.setPageEvent(event2);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach won't work as each time you create a new `PdfWriter`, a new pdf file is started. So you have two pdf writers creating separate pdfs which both are writing to the same file. Thus, you get a hodgepodge as output and are lucky if the result can be opened as a pdf at all!

Instead you can either switch page event listeners of the single writer at some time:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 145);
FooterPageEvent1 event1 = new FooterPageEvent1();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileOut);
writer.setPageEvent(event1);
document.open();
.....
writer.setPageEvent(null);
FooterPageEvent2 event2 = new FooterPageEvent2();
writer.setPageEvent(event2);
.....
```

Or you can implement a single page event listener with a boolean property that depending on the current value of the property creates one or the other footer. Between document parts you would simply toggle that property.